# javac -cp can not find class?

Tags: java, jar, javac

How to use the javac command, want to compile hello.java to hello.class, the file content is as follows: 
[image]

How to introduce other packages, the directory structure is as follows 
[image]

It's a mistake for me to run like this: 
e:\icenew2\hellotest>javac -sourcepath src hello.java
[image]

It's wrong to run like this ： javac -cp "src\com\zeroc\Ice*.class"  hello.java
[image]

Comment: Please don't use images to describe textual problems. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

We can use the wildcard character `*`:

```
javac -cp *; BackBenchers.java
```

Specifying destination directory:

```
javac -d classes backbenchers.java
```

**Note**: The compiler will complain if the specified directory does not exist, and it won’t create one.

If the source file is under a package, the compiler will create package structure in the destination directory.

Specifying source path directory:

```
javac -sourcepath src BackBenchers.java
```